# ruby on rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am scraping a website from a controller and putting it into a JSON response/view. The problem is that it appears to be caching the same result, although the content that I scrape is different. I'm totally lost on what to do.  I find links about how I can enable the cache on the pages, but not how to prevent rails from caching.

```
    class XXXXXController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /songs
  # GET /songs.json
  def index
    @xxx = xxxx.all


    @url = []
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://xxxxx.xxxx.org/xx/"))

    doc.xpath("//a[@class=\"replylink\"]").each { |node|
      thread = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://xxxxx.xxxx.org/xxx/" + node["href"]))

      thread.xpath("//blockquote[@class=\"postMessage\"]").each { | xx_post |
        xx_post.text.scan(/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(([a-zA-Z0-9]){11})/).each { | yt |
          @url << Regexp.last_match[1] if Regexp.last_match
        }    
      }
    }
  end
```

The site i am opening is changing once a second.

```
    json.array!(@url) do |url|
  json.url song_url(url, format: :json)

end
```

It still caches. It started doing this when I modified a css asset.

Comment: Show through code what you mean by 'it appears to be caching the same result, although the content that I scrape is different'.

Comment: are you in production mode?

Comment: yes, i am. i am new to rails so its very confusing

Answer (score 0):

I added json.cache!. New jbuilder file:

```
json.cache! @url do |asdf|
  json.array!(@url) do |url|
    json.url song_url(url, format: :json)
    #url
  end
end
```